# Message Notification

Tags: javascript, php

there has a script to display the message:

```
<? php
include "config.php";
$id = $_GET ['id'];
$query =mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id='$id'");
if ($query) {
echo '<script language = "javascript"> swal ({
title: "Warning!",
text: "Success Delete id!",
type: "success"
}, function () {
window.location.href = "index.php";
}); </ script> ';
?>
```

but the message doesn't appear?
Please help.
thanks

Comment: if($ query) space is there check the code

Comment: My guess is that you are being redirected to the index.php page before you can see the message

Comment: `<? php` space there doesn't look right ...`<?php` ... as well as the `$ query` comment earlier

Comment: `but the message doesn't appear?` does the page redirect? does the page load whatever library `swal` is? what DOES happen when you load this page? I mean, if this is the **whole** page, how is it "opened", is it through a `form` submit?

Comment: Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: Do you load SweetAlert (swal) anywhere?

Comment: Since nobody else is commenting on why your post is being downvoted, here are a few big reasons: #1, the code is messy. There is no indenting and improper spacing everywhere, and there's not a single comment. #2. You are making reference to a 3rd party library (SweetAlerts) without mentioning it at all in your post, and you don't even load it at all in your example, so swal() isn't a valid call, making it a bad code example since there's no way it would ever run.  #3. The surrounding content uses poor grammar and doesn't indicate anything you've tried in order to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

as `<script language = "javascript">` has been deprecated

also if `($ query)` is not a typo here then remove the space between the two which make it look like `($query)`